# mk dir syntax is incorrect

Tags: windows, batch

i'm a complete beginner, just trying batch files for the first time to backup this folder. Why does this not work? (error: incorrect syntax for both commands

```
mkdir "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\Lastpass backups\%date% - %TIME%"
copy "%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\databases\chrome-extension_hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd_0\*.*" "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\Lastpass backups\%date% - %TIME%"
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because %date% is returning a formatted date such as (depending on your locale) Wed 24/07/2013, and / is an invalid character for a path name

Comment: yes, thank you, I found out eventually.
ended up with

Comment: `
mkdir "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Lastpass backups\%date:~6,4%_%date:~3,2%_%date:~0,2% - %TIME:~0,2%_%TIME:~3,2%_%TIME:~6,2%" 
copy "%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\databases\chrome-extension_hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd_0\*.*" "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Lastpass backups\%date:~6,4%_%date:~3,2%_%date:~0,2% - %TIME:~0,2%_%TIME:~3,2%_%TIME:~6,2%"
pause
`

Comment: @thomas post your solution has an answer if you solve it yourself